# Finding which day of month?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-3.0

I am using Asp:calendar. I need to find the day of week of the date selected.
For example for the month of February,2014 if 27th is selected it should give value as 4th Thursday. Please help in this

Comment: Get a Calendar table man. It will change your life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Day Of Week through `DateTime.DayOfWeek` property. like:

```
DayOfWeek daOfWeek = youCalendar.SelectedDate.DayOfWeek;
```

To calculate the occurrence of the day in that particular month, Create a new `DateTime` starting from 1st of the month, Loop through to `SelectedDate` check for `DayOfWeek` equals to `SelectedDate.DayOfWeek` and increment a counter.

```
DateTime selecteDate = yourCalendar.SelectedDate;

DateTime startDate = new DateTime(selecteDate.Year, selecteDate.Month, 1);
int counter = 0;
while (startDate <= selecteDate)
{
    if (startDate.DayOfWeek == selecteDate.DayOfWeek)
        counter++;
    startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);

}
```